# How to align last 3 menu items to the right - Wordpress main menu

Tags: menus

I would like style the main horizontal Wordpress menu so that the first 3 items are aligned to the left and the last 3 items are aligned to the right.

This will create the appearance of two menus (with login, etc., on the right) but make it easy to restyle it to create a responsive menu with the last three items at the bottom.

MENU:

```
<UL> 
<li>1a</li><li>2a</li><li>3a</li> <-left    right-> <li>4a</li><li>5a</li><li>6a</li>
</UL>
```

Using float left and right causes the last 3 items to change order, I need them to stay in order.

I would like a solution that does not require creating a separate menu or changing the order of the menu items to make the float:right put them back in the right order.

I have tried various combinations of display:inline-block and text-align:left/right, with no luck.

EDIT: 
I would like to do this without adding markup into the menu itself. (Unless the answer also illustrates how to add markup into a Wordpress horizontal menu.)

Comment: This is purely a CSS issue and probably better suited for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I see what you mean. I did not initially specify in the question that I am talking about Wordpress menus. However it is about a Worpress menu, otherwise the answer given by Andrei Gheorghiu would be acceptable as well. However in a Wordpress menu I dont think it is so easy to add html markup at specific places.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the menu is WordPress or not, as you see in the answer, there is nothing specific to WordPress to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way with no markup changes and minimal CSS. [Live demo/fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/silb3r/1eyk7pa4/2/), code below:

```
<ul> 
  <li>1a</li><li>2a</li><li>3a</li><li>4a</li><li>5a</li><li>6a</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li:nth-last-child(1), li:nth-last-child(2), li:nth-last-child(3) {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your two groups (left and right aligned items) in two containers. You than set `float` `left`, respectively `right` on those containers.

```
<UL> 
    <div class="pull-left"><li>1a</li><li>2a</li><li>3a</li></div>
    <div class="pull-right"><li>4a</li><li>5a</li><li>6a</li></div>
</UL>
```

And make sure the inside elements have `display` set to `inline-block`. You also want to set `overflow` property of `ul` element to 'hidden', to make sure it expands to contain all the children, since both are floating.

```
.pull-left { float: left; }
.pull-right { float: right; }
.pull-left li, .pull-right li { display: inline-block; }
ul { overflow: hidden; }
```

Setting `overflow: hidden` for all the `ul` elements in your project might not be a very good idea, so you might want to find a parent selector of your `ul` and add it in front of the `ul` selector. (ex: `.some-container-class-here ul { overflow: hidden;}` )

Comment: I can see how this would work, but being a Wordpress menu, I don't know how to add the extra markup.